# How to statistically test whether the co-existing of events is more likely after a treatment (paired data)

Tags: categorical-data, binary-data, paired-data, mutual-information, association-measure

I have some nominal (binary) data at two time points. The data structure are as follows:

| participant | event A | event B | event C | event D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 Before | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 2 Before | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 3 Before | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | FALSE |
| 4 Before | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |

| participant | event A | event B | event C | event D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 After | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 2 After | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 3 After | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 4 After | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |

I have two mains:

1. Test if there are any events that significantly co-exist
2. Test if after the treatment there are any significant changes in the co-existence

In the above toy table, my intention is to show:

1. Before the treatment, there seems no events are significantly co-existing (maybe A and C are the most co-existing events, such that when A is TRUE, C is more likely to be also TRUE).
2. After the treatment, events A and B are co-existing
3. After the treatment, events A and B co-exist and changed (in terms of co-existence) significantly when compared with before treatment.

I am not sure if there is any method to test the above hypotheses. I tried to search for a test for mutual information, but seems it is not appropriate. Then, I looked at the correlation coefficient, but I am not sure if it can be used in nominal data. Would be great if you can suggest a method to accomplish the test in `R` (preferred but not a must).

Comment: What do you mean by *significantly co-exist*?

Comment: I mean whether the existence of event A can predict the existence of event B. Indeed, I found there is [phi coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient). I also found a tutorial [here](https://f-santos.gitlab.io/2020-04-01-comparing-correlation-coefficients.html), but not sure if there is something equivalence for phi coefficient.